# Android Notification sound defaulting back instead of playing custom sound

Tags: android, audio, notifications, mp3

Has anybody experienced this? I use `notification.sound` to set a custom sound and a phone still uses the default sound.

I copied a sound from `audio-resources.zip/audio/alarms/Instance.mp3`. ([You can download `audio-resources.zip` here](http://n0rp.chemlab.org/android/audio-resources.zip)). I copied it and moved/renamed it to `res/raw/notification.mp3`.

I am using this code to make the sound.

```
//Old way: notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/raw/notification");
```

That commented out line is what I was using. It made a sound, presumably the default notification sound. The other two lines are what I am using now.

The old way did not make a sound on the emulator, but it made a sound on the customer's phone (expected). The new way made the correct sound on the emulator, but the customer still hears the old sound.

- The customer has indeed installed the update. Confirmed by the server receiving a new versionCode (originally from AndroidManifest.xml) and the app telling the user he is up to date. (this is not a market app)
- The sound comes from a `BroadcastReceiver` which is triggered by the Alarm Manager
- I have tested on the emulator using the same download link from the same server and I can't recreate.
- The customer's sound "is nothing that resembles a beep". If you listen to `Instance.mp3`, you will know, it is clearly 5 beeps with about a quarter second between beeps.

Now the crazy thing about this is that I would expect the sound to be missing entirely, ***not*** to fail back to the default???

I will have the customer reboot his phone and do another clean test (which he has probably already done), but I don't have any more ideas. Do you have any?

Comment: Can you play the MP3 on a real phone? Playing on a desktop doesn't rule out issues with bitrate etc.

Comment: I don't know how to check the bitrate of the MP3, but it looks like [Android should always support at least *"Mono/Stereo 8-320Kbps constant (CBR) or variable bit-rate (VBR)"* but *"any given mobile device may provide support for additional formats"*.](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core)

Comment: Your question was very useful for me :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item resolved after rebooting the phone. Don't know why. It was not needed on the emulator. I guess the alarms sitting out there during the upgrade was not helpful.