# How to set notification with custom sound in android

Tags: android

I copied the mp3 (kalimba.mp3) file into the `raw` folder in the `res` folder. But when the notification is triggered it produces the default sound.

This is how I make a notification:

```
protected void GenerateNotify() {

    NotificationManager myNotificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
    Notification notification=new Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now,"hi",100);
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),as.class);
    PendingIntent contentintent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Hi","date", contentintent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.serviceproject/" + R.raw.kalimba);
    myNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. Try rebooting you emulator or phone.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682321/android-notification-sound-defaulting-back-instead-of-playing-custom-sound

Answer (score 118):

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysnd);
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

> if defined DEFAULT_SOUND, then the default sound overrides any sound

Comment: how to add .mp3 file in notification .

Comment: put your mp3 file into raw folder

Comment: If i don't write `notification.defaults` then what is possibility to play custom sound ?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, why does specifying the default lights and vibration make the sound work?

Comment: Have someone tried this with Android 8, this is not working for me anymore!

Comment: can is set notification sound from storage and expansion file ?

Answer (score 18):

`R.raw.kalimba` is an integer **resource ID;** you want the *name* of the sound resource in that `Uri`. So try:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
        + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/kalimba");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/notifysnd);
notification.setSound(sound);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should replace this line:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.serviceproject/" + R.raw.kalimba);
```

with this:

```
notification.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/kalimba"));
```

or in some cases:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/kalimba");
```

Answer (score 0):

I make this static function in HelperClass.java

```
    public static void givenotification(Context context,String message) {
         NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

         Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DesireActivity.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

         Notification notification = new Notification();
         NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
         builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

         notification = builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message).build();
         notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.kalimba);
         notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
     }
```

Then any Activity like in MainActivity 
       `HelperClass.givenotification(MainActivity.this,"Your Notification Message");`
OR in fragment
          `HelperClass.givenotification(getActivity(),"Your Notification Message");`

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented this way to  set custom Notification sound in my app.

```
  int notificationID=001;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.room);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Room Rent , Pay Room Rent");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, Its time to pay your Room Rent!");
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorViolet));
        mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.roommanagement.app/" + R.raw.notification_sound));

        if (mNotificationManager!=null){
            mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
        }
```

Hop this will help you.Thanks...