# I need to add notification sound dynamically from raw folder - Android

Tags: android, notifications, android-resources, resource-id

I have a "notificationsound.mp3" named file in my raw folder, along with many other sound files. I need to  dynamically add the sound files to my generated notifications . My approach included adding finding the resource id of the raw/soundfile ,and adding it . "con" is the context passed .
My code goes as follows

```
    //blah blah blah lines of code
   String soundname="notificationsound"; // this name will be changed dynamically which is passed via constructor
  int res_sound_id = con.getResources().getIdentifier(soundname, "raw", con.getPackageName());
   builder.setSound("android.resource://" + con.getPackageName() + "/"+ res_sound_id );
  //blah blah lines of code
```

Of course , I am gettning error in the builder.setSound() line , because of res_sound_id.
I did go through couple of links including [How to set notification with custom sound in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760168/how-to-set-notification-with-custom-sound-in-android)
Is there a better(& correct) of doing the same?

Comment: shows red underline below this function , hint shows as follows :
"The method setSound(Uri) in the type NotificationCompat.Builder is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Comment: I'd try the solution from [this answer to your linked-to question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13784557/115145), which creates a `Uri` and skips the pointless `getIdentifier()` call.

Comment: because "notificationsound" written here is just an example, string will be passed as a sound name , and thus I cannot append "/notificationsound"

Comment: Then append `"/"+yourStringVariable`, where `yourStringVariable` is "string will be passed as a sound name". You still do not need the `getIdentifier()` call.

Comment: you mean :
 builder.setSound("android.resource://" + con.getPackageName() + "/" +"notificationsound" );
It doesn'k work. Wrong syntax

Comment: You forgot the `raw` part. This is included in [this answer to your linked-to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760168/how-to-set-notification-with-custom-sound-in-android/13784557#13784557).

Comment: NO,didn't work here, there notification.sound is called 
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(con);
builder.setSound(Uri ) is called , what should be the uri?

Comment: If [this answer to your linked-to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760168/how-to-set-notification-with-custom-sound-in-android/13784557#13784557), and the other answers, are correct, it should be `Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + yourStringVariable)`, where `yourStringVariable` is "string will be passed as a sound name".

Comment: int res_sound_id = con.getResources().getIdentifier(soundname, "raw", con.getPackageName());
Uri u= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + con.getPackageName() + "/" +res_sound_id );
builder.setSound(u);

Answer (score 2):

Well here is the solution for the same.
1) get the resource id
2) make a Uri object 
3) call the .setSound() method

```
   String s="soundname" // you can change it dynamically
   int res_sound_id = con.getResources().getIdentifier(soundname, "raw", con.getPackageName());
   Uri u= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + con.getPackageName() + "/" +res_sound_id );
   builder.setSound(u);
```