# How to add custom notification sound in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have to manage notification and for that I need to manage custom sound when it comes. So do you have any idea how we can do this?

I already copied sound file to my raw folder, so anyone have any ideas how I can implement it to my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760168/how-to-set-notification-with-custom-sound-in-android

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Firstly make the folder in **Resource** (res) name it **raw** and put the file (YOUR_SOUND_FILE.MP3) in it and than use below lines of code for custom sound

```
   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            SlidingMenuActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("isInbox", true);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

**Use these lines of code for custom sound**

```
 notification.sound =Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.FILE_NAME);//Here is FILE_NAME is the name of file that you want to play


    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

**EDIT UPDATE**

For the Oreo and higher , you need to check the **SDK_VERSION** and use the `setSound` method of the `NotificationChannel`

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.FILE_NAME);  //Here is FILE_NAME is the name of file that you want to play

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
                "YOUR CHANNEL NAME",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();

            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, 
                    context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            mChannel.setDescription(msg);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setSound(sound, attributes); // This is IMPORTANT


            if (mNotificationManager != null)
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
```

Comment: How to play custom notification sound above 7.0 ? I have tried with path `file://`,`content://` and `FILE PROVIDER` not able to play custom sound,only system sound are able to play.

Comment: Waiting for your response. what I have tried is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException

Comment: @SagarHudge Please refer above updated the solution and let me know in case of concern

Comment: instead of `raw.FILE_NAME` can I use `file:///storage/emulated/0/MIUI/.ringtone/cowboy.ogg` or `uri.getPath()`

Comment: Means, u need to play notification from the device stored file?

Comment: yes when I am trying to play getting `FileUriExposedException` on `URI`

Comment: any update on this please

Comment: @SagarHudge From my point of view, u can not be play the external file for the notification..You need to put inside the raw folder

Comment: On Xiaomi mi9 I had to enable notification sound in application settings (Notifications>Allow sound)

Android 10, MIUI 11.0.3

Comment: @mkrasowski Ok thanks for the info, Will check on the respected device.

Comment: @Ravindra Kushwaha, thanks

Comment: @AlexeyBilousov happy to help you..Have a good day

Answer (score 11):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("I want food")
    .setContentText(notificationcontent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pi)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE);
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(contexto, R.raw.your_sound);
mp.start();
manager.notify(73195, builder.build());
```

Comment: Yes. This is working but default notification sound also been added. How to stop that?

Comment: id also like to know the answer to this

Comment: @SsubratRrudra - you might have figured out by now. But for someone else setSound(null) would do.

Comment: Best answer so far among all. It solved my problem easily and you don't need to worry about the android OS version issues.

Comment: This solution seems not work when app in background.