# How would I make custom notification sound in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, android-notifications

I want to add an mp3 that I have stored in firebase as my custom notification sound using the URL in firebase.

Here is code to add it if the media file was in the resource folder:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            SlidingMenuActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("isInbox", true);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.FILE_NAME);  //Here is FILE_NAME is the name of file that you want to play

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
                "YOUR CHANNEL NAME",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();

            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, 
                    context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            mChannel.setDescription(msg);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setSound(sound, attributes); // This is IMPORTANT


            if (mNotificationManager != null)
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
```

How would I do it using the Firebase storage URL given to my MP3 file in firebase?

Source code: [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398381/how-to-add-custom-notification-sound-in-android)