# How to show FCM notification with no sound in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using flutter local notification in a project which has custom sound. In settings, there is option to disable notifications. I want to show notifications but with no sound i.e. silent notification if user has disabled notifications from app settings.
I have tried following case but no use.

```
    AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  channelID,
  channelName,
  importance: Importance.max,
  groupId: groupKey,
  playSound: settingsHive.getNotiSettings() == "false" ? true : false,
  sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(sound.split('.').first),
);
```

Please any help or idea ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398381/how-to-add-custom-notification-sound-in-android

Comment: I am asking in flutter

Comment: flutter plugin via native code