# Can I download an audio file and use it for push notification sound in Android?

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to download a file and store it somewhere in my app, for example `SharedPreferences`, then I want to play it when a remote push notification is sent.

Is it possible? If so, where is the best place to store this audio file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760168/how-to-set-notification-with-custom-sound-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970748/how-to-set-notification-with-custom-sound

Answer (score 0):

use **raw/** folder

> Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources
>   with a raw InputStream, call Resources.openRawResource() with the
>   resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.
>
> However, if you need access to original file names and file hierarchy,
>   you might consider saving some resources in the assets/ directory
>   (instead of res/raw/). Files in assets/ are not given a resource ID,
>   so you can read them only using AssetManager.

And after Downloading use it like this

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.soundclip);
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.start();
```