# Can I modify the default notification sound in android?

Tags: android

Is there any way that I could modify the default notification sound in android application development and convert it into something good like a sound from guitar string ? If yes, please suggest me a way....

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13760398/3303075

Answer (score 0):

In the settings you can change your sound :D. Go to Settings -> Ring and Vibrate -> Ringtone!

I don't know if I understand it but if you want to modify your notification sound you will have to find the file of it which is in the "system"-directory of your phone. But for this you have too root your phone!